# Getting a Blank Screen instead of Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am working on a Music Player app that consists some fragments and adapters. The main screen of the app has a recycler view that shows a list of songs with the help of adapter and fragment. But when I am running my app I am getting a blank screen. What I am missing? Here is the code of the app: (Please comment, if any other file needed to attach).

My MainActivity.kt File:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

var navigationDrawerIconList : ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

var images_for_navdrawer = intArrayOf(R.drawable.navigation_allsongs, R.drawable.navigation_favorites,
        R.drawable.navigation_settings, R.drawable.navigation_aboutus)

object Statified{
    var drawerLayout : DrawerLayout?=null
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
   MainActivity.Statified.drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)

   // drawerLayout=findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout


    navigationDrawerIconList.add("All Songs")
    navigationDrawerIconList.add("Favorites")
    navigationDrawerIconList.add("Settings")
    navigationDrawerIconList.add("About Us")

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this@MainActivity, MainActivity.Statified.drawerLayout, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    MainActivity.Statified.drawerLayout?.setDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    val mainScreenFragment = MainScreenFragment()
    this.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.details_fragment, mainScreenFragment, "MainScreenFragment")
            .commit()




    //Navigation Drawer

    var _navigationAdapter = NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationDrawerIconList, images_for_navdrawer, this@MainActivity)

    _navigationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    var navigation_recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.navigation_recycler_view)
    navigation_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    navigation_recycler_view.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    navigation_recycler_view.adapter = _navigationAdapter
    navigation_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)


  //  var navigation_recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.navigation_recycler_view)
    //navigation_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    //navigation_recycler_view.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
}

}
```

My MainScreenFragment.kt File:

```
class MainScreenAdapter(_songDetails:ArrayList<Songs>, _context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainScreenAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

var songDetail: ArrayList<Songs>?=null
var mContext: Context?=null

init {
    this.songDetail = _songDetails
    this.mContext = _context
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {

    val songObject = songDetail?.get(position)
    holder?.trackTitle?.text = songObject?.songTitle
    holder?.trackArtist?.text = songObject?.artist
    holder?.contentHolder?.setOnClickListener({
        val songPlayingFragment = SongPlayingFragment()
        var args = Bundle()
        args.putString("songArtist",songObject?.artist)
        args.putString("path", songObject?.songData)
        args.putString("songTitle", songObject?.songTitle)
        args.putInt("SongId", songObject?.songId?.toInt() as Int)
        args.putInt("songPosition", position)
        args.putParcelableArrayList("songData", songDetail)
        songPlayingFragment.arguments = args
        (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.details_fragment,songPlayingFragment)
                .commit()
    })

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.row_custom_mainscreen_adapter,parent,false)

    return MyViewHolder(itemView)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    if(songDetail == null){
        return 0
    } else{
        return (songDetail as ArrayList<Songs>).size
    }

}

class MyViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    var trackTitle: TextView? = null
    var trackArtist: TextView? = null
    var contentHolder: RelativeLayout? = null

    init {
        trackTitle = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.trackTitle)
        trackArtist = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.trackArtist)
        contentHolder = view.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.contentRow)
    }

}
}
```

and my MainScreenFragment.kt File:

```
class MainScreenFragment : Fragment() {


var getSongList : ArrayList<Songs>? = null
var nowPlayingBottomBar: RelativeLayout?=null
var playPauseButton: ImageView?=null
var songTitle: TextView?=null
var visibleLayout: RelativeLayout?=null
var noSongs: RelativeLayout?=null
var recyclerView: RecyclerView?= null

var myActivity:Activity?=null

var _mainScreenAdapter : MainScreenAdapter?=null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    activity.title = "All songs"
    visibleLayout = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.visibleLayout)
    noSongs = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.noSongs)
    nowPlayingBottomBar = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.hiddenBarMainScreen)
    songTitle = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.songTitleMainScreen)
    playPauseButton = view?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.playpauseButton)
    (nowPlayingBottomBar as RelativeLayout).isClickable = false
    recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.contentMain)

    if (getSongList == null) {
        getSongList = getSongsFromPhone()
        if (getSongList == null) {
            visibleLayout?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            noSongs?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(MainScreenFragment::class.java.simpleName, " Data already there")
    }



    getSongList = getSongsFromPhone()
    _mainScreenAdapter = MainScreenAdapter(getSongList as ArrayList<Songs>, activity)
    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    (recyclerView as RecyclerView).adapter = _mainScreenAdapter
    return view



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   /* val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false)
    visibleLayout = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.visibleLayout)
    noSongs = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.noSongs)
    nowPlayingBottomBar = view?.findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.hiddenBarMainScreen)
    songTitle = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.songTitleMainScreen)
    playPauseButton = view?.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.playPauseButton)
    recyclerView = view?.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.contentMain)


    return view*/
}

fun getSongsFromPhone(): ArrayList<Songs>{
    var arrayList = ArrayList<Songs>()
    var contentResolver = myActivity?.contentResolver
    var songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    var songCursor = contentResolver?.query(songUri, null, null, null, null)
    if(songCursor!=null && songCursor.moveToFirst()){
        val songId = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
        val SongTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex((MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
        val songArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
        val songData = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
        val dateIndex = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED)

        while(songCursor.moveToNext()){
            var currentId = songCursor.getLong(songId)
            var currentTitle = songCursor.getString(SongTitle)
            var currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist)
            var currentData = songCursor.getString(songData)
            var currentDate = songCursor.getString(dateIndex)
        }
    }
    return arrayList
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    getSongList = getSongsFromPhone()
   _mainScreenAdapter = MainScreenAdapter(getSongList as ArrayList<Songs>, myActivity as Context)
    val mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(myActivity)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
    recyclerView?.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    recyclerView?.adapter = _mainScreenAdapter
}


override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    myActivity = context as Activity
}

override fun onAttach(activity: Activity?) {
    super.onAttach(activity)
    myActivity = activity
}

}
```

FragmentMainScreen.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:clickable="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/visibleLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contentMain">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/hiddenBarMainScreen"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="31dp"
            android:background="@drawable/pause_icon"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/defaultMusic"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/now_playing_bar_eq_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Now Playing"
            android:id="@+id/nowPlaying"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/defaultMusic"
            android:textColor="#bdbdbd"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/songTitleMainScreen"
            android:layout_below="@id/nowPlaying"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="160dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="..."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nowPlaying"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/nowPlaying"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/noSongs">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="You do not have any Songs"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/header">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/echo_logo"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_recycler_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Check your view hierarchy using Layout Inspector, and see which all views are there on screen

Comment: Can you paste the XML of MainActivity?